# Reverting image maps to functions

Tags: javascript, html, imagemapster

I have an image and when you click on it, it goes to another image with a function and an image map. But on the next image there's text saying "back to other image" but I can't get it to go to the previous image.

The user clicks on the mainmenu.png and it goes to moreinfo.png, how do I make it go back to mainmenu.png?

```
<a href="quiz.html"><img src="img/mainmenu.png" alt="" style= "width: 15em; height: 25em;" id="moreinfo" usemap="#map"; /></a>

<map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="46,335,188,364" onclick="changeImage()">
</map>

<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage(){

        if (document.getElementById("moreinfo").src == "img/moreinfo.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("moreinfo").src = "img/moreinfo.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("moreinfo").src = "img/moreinfo.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<area shape="rect" coords="46,335,188,364" onclick="toggleImage()">


function toggleImage(){
  var img = document.getElementById("moreinfo");
  img.src = img.src.indexOf("moreinfo.png")!=-1?"img/mainmenu.png":"img/moreinfo.png";
}
```